# Structuring Routes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my application, I have the concept of events. Each event can be booked by a user, and also unbooked if that user needs to cancel.

My event routes look like this:

```
Route::get('events/search', 'EventsController@search');
Route::get('events/past', 'EventsController@past');
Route::get('events/{id}/invite', [
    'as' => 'invite', 'uses' => 'EventsController@invite'
]);
Route::get('events/{id}/invite/groups', [
    'as' => 'inviteGroups', 'uses' => 'EventsController@inviteGroups'
]);
Route::get('events/{id}/duplicate', [
    'as' => 'duplicate', 'uses' => 'EventsController@duplicate'
]);
Route::get('events/{id}/book', [
    'as' => 'book', 'uses' => 'EventsController@book'
]);
Route::get('events/{id}/unbook', [
    'as' => 'unbook', 'uses' => 'EventsController@unbook'
]);
Route::post('events/{id}/groups', [
    'as' => 'addGroups', 'uses' => 'EventsController@addGroups'
]);
Route::post('events/{id}/helpers', [
    'as' => 'addHelpers', 'uses' => 'EventsController@addHelpers'
]);
Route::resource('events', 'EventsController');
```

I'm having difficulty with the "book" route, which throws the following error when I hit it:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
```

The route users a function that attaches a user to an event, and then returns that user to the event page.

I'm sure its an order of precedence issue, but no matter how I organize the routes, I keep hitting that error. This is the only route on the list that's causing problems. Are there any best practices on route organization to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the book is a get and not a post?

Comment: The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception suggests you are using a method other than the one specified for the route, which in this case is a `get`.